# opening an office program will empty the clipboard

Tags: windows-xp, clipboard, microsoft-office-2003

Steps:

copy text

open word, excel, new email from outlook, etc

paste (nothing happens)

I have to copy it again and paste it into the already open window. This doesn't happen with other vendor programs or simple programs like notepad. It also doesn't happen all the time, but more than not.

Anyone know what's up?

windows XP, office 2007.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you copying your text from?

Comment: Could be from anywhere, notepad, outlook, word, toad, dreamweaver, internet explorer, firefox...

Comment: Uninstalled Cisco WebEx Productivity Tools worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft usually recommend you to try starting Word/Excel/Outlook without any addons to see if that cures the program and if so to disable the addons until your figure out which one causes the problem and the contact the authors.

The other type of programs that can cause problems are desktop sharing/collaboration programs, so if you have any of these you can try disabling them.

Comment: I removed the add-ins and testing it.  Like I said, it doesn't always do it.  Thanks for the suggestion, I'll let you know how it works out!

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Samsung Printer and happened to install the Easy Document Printer software, remove it. Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from this until today. Try unchecking the "Send to Bluetooth" com add-on. In Outlook...

```
File --> Options --> Add-Ons --> COM Add-Ons --> Go.
```

I'm using Office 2010, Windows 10 on a Dell Latitude E6540, but this would appear to be a very widespread and long-running issue. What a cracker.